What features do I lose by running containers via `podman run --in-pod=0`
I have Windows 10 WSL2, when I run containers I set export PODMAN_USERNS=keep-id, but it had no effect until I started running containers with --in-pod=0, can someone explain - what did I lose when I disabled the "in-pod" mode?
I am only interested in local development, production will be built by a separate specialist.
